# Paying for activated abilities of newly spoiled card Halo Fountain

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Halo Fountain is a newly spoiled card for New Capenna:

[image: Text]

Now say you turn Halo Fountain into a creature (there's a variety of methods to do this, say Karn, Silver Golem for example).

Say you wanted to activate its first ability. You pay W, tap it, then untap it. Does that work?

Alternatively, since you can pay costs in any order, can you pay W, untap it, then tap it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, because you can pay costs in any order, you can use an animated halo fountain itself as part of the untap tapped creature(s) costs. Untapping as a cost is rare, but this works the same way as sacrifice based additional costs have in the past.